# Permission Denied Error when trying to reload ~/.bash_profile

Tags: bash, permissions

Hello people I am trying to reload the "~/.bash_profile" but I get the "Permission Denied Error" and "sudo" does not work is there a way I can reload the "~/.bash_profile" because it's an integral step in the installation of RVM. 
Please help any assistance is appreciated.
mojo706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`. ~/.bash_profile`

Sam

Comment: Hey Sam thanks for the quick reply but that's what brings the "permission denied" error. After that I tried to use sudo but it refused.

Comment: Ok Sam thanks your answer was actually correct! I restarted the Terminal and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: no problem! the trick is to add the point at the beggining of the command!, have a nice one!

Comment: yes that was the trick